# Add a field to represent a condtionally calculated value

Tags: mysql, view

I'm trying to add a new column to my table that is the difference between two others, as shown below.

```
ALTER TABLE GB
ADD COLUMN spread INT;

UPDATE GB
SET spread = (home_score-away_score)
WHERE GB.team = GB.home;

UPDATE GB
SET spread = (away_score-team_score)
WHERE GB.team = GB.away;
```

Comment: so, what is the issue?

Comment: You can use insert/update Trigger.

Comment: @David Allen Stern - can you share current table structure?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to create a view instead of adding a third column to represent a derived information. In this way your view will have updated information all the time.

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS(
   SELECT *,(CASE 
        WHEN GB.team = GB.home THEN
             home_score-away_score
        ELSE 
             away_score-team_score 
        END
   )AS spread FROM GB
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its better not to create additional column. You can get your required result easily using `select` statement as shown below

```
select id,team,home,away,home_score,away_score,team_score,
if(GB.team = GB.home,home_score-away_score,away_score-team_score) as spread  from gb
```

If you need small modification, please let me know before down voting